# How prove this sequence converge $\{x_{n}\}=2^{\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

i need help with this exercise i need prove the serie

$\{x_{n}\}=2^{\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}}$ Converge.

I know for limits, this

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2^{\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}}=2$

Now, i need prove that result and i finish my exercise.

I try this:

Let $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ then $|x_{n}-2|<\epsilon$

Now i want find that $N$

I try this: $|2^{\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}}-2|=|2^{1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}-2|=|2\times2^{-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}-2|=|2(2^{-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}-1)|=2|2^{-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}-1|=2|\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}}-1|=2(1-\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}})$ But i'm stuck in that part, can someone help me?

Comment: Examine first the convergence of $\log_{2}(x_{m})$.  Now, $\log_{2}$ is a continuous function on the positive abscissa semiaxis.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try this a bit different than usual. It is trivial that $2^{(2^n-1)/2^n} > 0$, because the statement $2^n > 0$ holds for all $ n \in \mathbb{R}$. We now show that the sequence is monotonically increasing for positive $n$, i.e. that
$$2^{(2^{n+1}-1)/2^{n+1}}>2^{(2^n-1/2)/2^n}$$
It is now clear that 
$$2^n-1/2 > 2^n - 1 \implies \frac{2^n-1/2}{2^n} > \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$$
and since $2^n$ is monotonically increasing for $n>0$, so is your function. Since we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 2$, our function must clearly be bounded by $2$ for positive $n$

Comment: I think you should drop limit. Monotonic [and bounded] sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ converge.